# Проброска порта 5432 в docker

Tags: база-данных, docker, docker-compose

Опыт работы с docker пока еще мал. На порте 5432 локальной машины бд, как прокинуть этот порт внутрь контейнера например на порт 1234, чтобы я работая с приложением через docker мог обратиться к локальной бд? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Попробуйте в описании docker-сервиса указать:
`ports:
      - "5432: 5432"`
Подключение по имени сервиса + порт, пример: `db:5432`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Запуская контейнер можно задать маппинг портов `[внешний_порт]:[порт_внутри_контейнера]` через ключ `-p 1234:5432`

Например `docker run -d -p 1234:5432 postgres`

**UPD:**
В запущенный контейнер нельзя вносить изменения, поэтому придется создать новый контейнер, взяв за основу исходный.

1. Остановить контейнер
   `docker stop [имя_контейнера]`
2. Закоммитить контейнер
   `docker commit [имя_контейнера] [новое_имя_контейнера]`
3. Запустить новый контейнер
   `docker run -p 1234:5432 -p 5432:5432 [новое_имя_контейнера]`

Comment: Подскажите, если уже есть зависимость [порт_внутри_контейнера]:[внешний_порт] я смогу добавить еще одну [внешний_порт]:[порт_внутри_контейнера]?

Comment: @parabol обновил ответ, но в будущем задавайте новый вопрос, если он отличается от начального вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score -2):

Если тебе из контейнера надо обращаться к базе, которая запущена не в докере, а на хостовой ОС, то на Windows/MacOS используй специальное имя `host.docker.internal`, которое докер разрезолвит в имя компьютера. Например, `host.docker.internal:5432`

На Linux, кажется, просто по настоящему имени хоста можно обратиться.